# Join annotated queryset

Tags: django, django-orm

## The problem

My Django models are laid out like this:

```py
class Event(models.Model):
    …

class Participation(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    …

class Rating(models.Model):
    participation = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    …

class Item(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    …
```

```
Event <-- Participation
 ^         ^
 |         |
Item <-- Rating
```

There's a custom [manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) on `Item` with a method returning an [annotated queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) with a few calculations and [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) based on related `Rating` objects and such (say a field called `mean_rating`). Those results can be seen in a dedicated view.

My goal is to create another view which displays a list of `Participation` objects but with a queryset joined with the one from my custom `ItemManager` that gives me access to the annotated fields on the `Item` queryset as well:

```
Participation.objects.annotate(
    rating_count=Count(rating), 
    sum_of_mean_rating=Sum(F("mean_rating"))  # field on ItemQueryset
)
```

## My take on this

I tried using the [Prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) object with a custom queryset and this makes the annotated fields available by joining the querysets in Python (i.e. `object.related_object.annotated_field` works) but I'd like to join them in the database for additional annotation.

I also thought about using a custom [base manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Model._base_manager) which (opposed to a default manager) would also handle relationships. But the `ItemQuerySet` is a filtered one and its manager method requires a parameter that I couldn't supply in a `BaseManager`.